# Python スレッド処理の記述の中にもう1つスレッド処理を作りたい

Tags: python

2つのスレッド処理を組み合わせてプログラムを組みたいのですが
エラーが出てしまい、うまく行きません。

1つ目が、1秒ごとにGUIをprintを行うプログラム(threadingGUI.py)です。
tkinterというライブラリでGUIを作っているのですが、普通にwhileループを回すとGUIがフリーズします。
whileループを回してもGUIがフリーズしないように、threading処理をしてあります。
(参考記事：https://teratail.com/questions/147384)

**threadingGUI.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import time

class threadingGUI():
    def __init__(self):
        self.frame=1
        self.stop_flag=False
        self.thread=None

    def time_count(self):
        while not self.stop_flag:
            print(self.frame)
            self.frame=self.frame+1
            time.sleep(1)

    def start(self):
        if not self.thread:
            self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.time_count)
            self.stop_flag=False
            self.thread.start()

    def stop(self):
        if self.thread:
            self.stop_flag=True
            self.thread.join()
            self.thread=None

    def GUI_start(self):
        root=tk.Tk()
        Button001=tk.Button(root,text="Start",command=self.start)
        Button001.pack()
        Button002=tk.Button(root,text="Stop",command=self.stop)
        Button002.pack()
        root.mainloop()

        self.stop_flag=True
        self.thread.join()

t = threadingGUI()
t.GUI_start()
```

2つ目が、一定周期でプログラムを実行するためのプログラムです。
単純にsleepをするだけだと、プログラムの実行時間分のズレが発生するようなので
sleepとthreadingを組み合わせています。
(参考記事：https://qiita.com/montblanc18/items/05715730d99d450fd0d3)

**threading_and_sleep.py**

```
import time
import threading

def worker():
    print(time.time())
    time.sleep(8)

def scheduler(interval, f, wait = True):
    base_time = time.time()
    next_time = 0
    while True:
        t = threading.Thread(target = f)
        t.start()
        if wait:
            t.join()
        next_time = ((base_time - time.time()) % interval) or interval
        time.sleep(next_time)

scheduler(1, worker, False)
```

threadingGUI.pyと、threading_and_sleep.pyを組み合わせて
以下のように、なるべく正確に一定間隔でprintするプログラム(threading_and_sleepGUI.py)を書いてみようとしたのですが、実行すると、startボタン実行時にGUIがフリーズしてしまいます。

**threading_and_sleepGUI.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import time

class threading_and_sleepGUI():
    def __init__(self):
        self.stop_flag=False
        self.thread=None

    def worker(self):
        print(time.time())
        time.sleep(8)

    def scheduler(self,interval, f, wait = True):
        base_time = time.time()
        next_time = 0
        while not self.stop_flag:
            t = threading.Thread(target = f)
            t.start()
            if wait:
                t.join()
            next_time = ((base_time - time.time()) % interval) or interval
            time.sleep(next_time)

    def start(self):
        if not self.thread:
            self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.scheduler(1, self.worker, False))
            self.stop_flag=False
            self.thread.start()

    def stop(self):
        if self.thread:
            self.stop_flag=True
            self.thread.join()
            self.thread=None

    def GUI_start(self):
        root=tk.Tk()
        Button001=tk.Button(root,text="Start",command=self.start)
        Button001.pack()
        Button002=tk.Button(root,text="Stop",command=self.stop)
        Button002.pack()
        root.mainloop()

        self.stop_flag=True
        self.thread.join()

t = threading_and_sleepGUI()
t.GUI_start()
```

スレッド処理の最中にスレッド処理が含まれていると不具合が起きてしまうのでしょうか？
どうしたらGUIをフリーズさせず、一定間隔でprintを行うように出来ますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.scheduler(1, self.worker, False))`でtargetの引数指定の方法が間違いです。

[class threading.Thread(group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(), kwargs={}, *, daemon=None)](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread)

> args は target を呼び出すときの引数タプルです。デフォルトは () です。

正しくは、`self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.scheduler, args=(1, self.worker, False))`になります。